# Match multiline and print it in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I want to match a multiline regex and print only the lines that match:

```
$ cat test.txt
line1
line2
line3
$ perl -ne 'print if /line2.line3/s' test.txt
$
```

This regex actually matches `line2\nline3` but it is not printed. regex101 [verifies](https://www.regex101.com/r/aQ2xK3/1) that it is matched.

Using command switch `0777` prints the lines that match but then it prints non-matched lines too:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print if /line2.line3/s' test.txt
line1
line2
line3
```

Using `0777` in a substitution regex works as expected:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/line2.line3/replaced/s' test.txt
line1
replaced
```

I would like to learn if it is possible to print only lines that match a multiline regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`print` without an argument prints `$_`. If you use `-0777`, the whole file is read into `$_`, so if there is a match, you print the whole file. If you only want to show the matching parts, you can use

```
 perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /(line2.line3)/sg' test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you don't need `if`,  `while` or regex groups.

```
 perl -0777 -ne 'print /line2\sline3\s/sg' test.txt
```

---

Output:

```
line2
line3
```

---

Regex Explanation:

```
line2\sline3\s
--------------

Match the character string “line2” literally (case insensitive) «line2»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\s»
Match the character string “line3” literally (case insensitive) «line3»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\s»
```

Comment: Could you please explain why does this work? The only difference between this and my above command is that this one doesn't have `if`.

Comment: You might need to add the final newline to the regex, then.

Comment: @MertNuhoglu I guess choroba answer as more to explain than mine, it's a very simple perl regex that prints a match. I've updated my answer with an regex explanation.

Comment: @choroba noted, I've add `\s` at the end. tks.

Comment: Another alternative is `perl -0777 -pe 'print unless s/line2.*line3\s//sg' test`

Comment: @Joshua I thinks there's an extra slash `/` at the end, apart from that, it should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant considering the end of the lines could be:

```
perl -0777 -ne '($,, $\) = ("\n")x2; print /(^line2$)\s(^line3$)/msg'
```

Comparison:

```
$ cat test.txt 
line1
line2
line3
line1
line2 line3
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print /line2\sline3\s/sg' test.txt
line2
line3
line2 line3
$ perl -0777 -ne '($,, $\) = ("\n")x2; print /(^line2$)\s(^line3$)/gms' test.txt
line2
line3
```

The `m` modifier allows for using `^` and `$` in a multiline context. The `g` modifier makes the regex loop over the string. The `s` modifier is not needed in this case, but some prefer to always have it. The groups makes the list the regex evaluates to return two items per match. Finally, the values print uses for list separators (`$,`) and for the end of the list (`$\`), have to be set to `"\n"`.

Version arguably simpler/better and closer to the solution above:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print /line2\nline3\n/sg' test.txt
```